# "interim multos habes quorum scripta nescio an satis ordinentur."

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In Seneca's *Moral Letters* (39):

> Scribam ergo quod vis, sed meo more; interim multos habes quorum scripta nescio an satis ordinentur.

How is *ordinentur* functioning here. The perfect/participle *scripta ordinata sint* would mean "are arranged/ordered" which makes sense, but here it is in present and seems to mean something somewhat different.

The Leob renders this almost as if *ordinor* were a deponent verb (which not indication to that was found): "I shall therefore write exactly what you wish, but I shall do it in my own way; until then, you have many authors whose works will presumably keep your ideas sufficiently in order."

So what does *ordinentur* mean here? How does the Loeb translation work here?

Comment: *Ordinata sint* would be "have been arranged"; it's *ordinentur* that would in fact mean "are (being) arranged". The Loeb translation seems too free, though.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, missing an explicit agent, I opted/forced for a stative reading which is manifestly wrong  . on a second reading it just  seems like *ordinari* can mean something like "to make sense"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have stumbled upon a particularly controversial locus, and several versions of the Latin, as well as different translations can be found.

Here is [D. J. W. Olshausen's German translation](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Uebersetzung_der_s%C3%A4mmtlichen_Briefe_des/8bc9AAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA120&printsec=frontcover), 1811:

> Einstweilen hast Du viele, deren Schriften man wohl nur nicht in gehöriger Ordung lieset.
> *In the mean time, you have many, whose writings, I think, people are just not reading in the right order.*

Then A. Pauly (*that* Pauly!) in his [1833 German translation](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Werke/JZFWAAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA1558&printsec=frontcover) writes:

> Inzwischen hast Du ja Viele, deren Schriften man wohl, nur nicht in gehöriger Ordnung liest.
> *In the mean time, you have many, whose writings are read well enough, but not in the right order.*

… and adds a footnote:

> So *Olshausen.* Der Sinn der Worte: *Interim multos habes, quorum scripta nescio an satis ordinent*, ist mir zweifelhaft. Gebrauchte vielleicht Seneca *nescio an* gegen den Gebrauch der Späteren affirmativ, und wollte sagen: – „deren Schriften den Geist vielleicht schon genugsam zu ordnen vermögen“ –?
> *According to *Olshausen*. The meaning of the words: *Interim multos habes, quorum scripta nescio an satis ordinent*, is dubious to me. Did Seneca perhaps use *nescio an* affirmatively, contrary to the usage of later writers, and wanted to say: – “whose writings are perhaps able to put the mind in proper order” –?*

Actually I think he does *not* exactly follow Olshausen here, but that is a minor squibble that has more to do with German than Latin. And why in the world would Seneca *not* use *nescio an* affirmatively, as every textbook of Classical Latin teaches us? (Pauly gets schooled on this point [here](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Seneca_philosophus/ZnDRAAAAMAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=RA4-PA22&printsec=frontcover) by one A. E. Schnell of Bern.) But note the most important point: Pauly seem to have thought the verb was *active*! They presumably had Seneca editions which said *ordinent*.

And note how his own suggested translation not only changes the emphasis of *nescio an* to the affirmative; he completely changes the meaning and is in line with your Loeb translation: the subject of *ordinent* is now not some anonymous public as with Olshausen, but the *scripta*.

Another philologist in possession of such an edition was the eminent [J. N. Madvig](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Io_Nic_Madvigii_Adversaria_critica_ad_sc/18AkAAAAMAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA475&printsec=frontcover), to whom, however, *ordinent* makes no sense at all, but who suggests *ordines* instead:

> *Interim multos habes, quorum scripta nescio an satis ordinent.* Quem aut quid? et quid hoc est, scripta philosophorum aliquid aut aliquem ordinare? Scribendum videtur: *quorum scripta nescio an satis **ordines**. Sume in manus indicem philosophorum* (ut eo in ordinandis scriptis utare). Cum scriptum esset *ordinesume*, factum est *ordinent*.

---

Thus, my best guess would be that the Loeb translation is also based on the active form, and the answer to Madvig's *quem aut quid?* is something like: *mentem vel cogitationes lectoris*. But the passive form, which seems to have been adopted by editors eventually (for whatever reason), is incompatible with that translation. Both the active and the passive form can be translated as “which I think are ordered well enough” (by the general public), which can be understood as most readers putting the writings in the right order for reading them (or perhaps for ranking them?).

Comment: Ha! thanks for the intensive research. I've just looked the Loeb's Latin and it indeed reads *ordinent* - I should be more careful next time (though usually they put a footnote when there are several versions - this time it was missing.) . I don't see how the passive can mean "are ordered well enough" since it is present subjective it implies action happening right now/tomorrow but the *scripta* are already done.

Comment: I also find the active *ordinent* strange. I've once read somewhere that netural nouns do not usually function as agents, but since then I've encountered dozens examples of this type, and yet I don't remember ever seeing ppp substantive being an agent for such real active verb such as *ordo*.  Maybe this is a subject to another question though.

Comment: @d_e My "the writings are ordered" is supposed to be present tense, but I guess the English would be clearer if I wrote: "Are **being** ordered well enough." The idea being that readers out there can constantly be observed putting the writings in order for their reading. I also find the *ordinent* strange; you can imagine the subject being anonymous people, but this is also quite unusual (except in words like *dicunt*). And why is the order that important at all? Overall this remains a dark passage.

Comment: I see. Yeah... somewhat obscure passage indeed.